# JspException: Error reading the child resources of parent folder "/warrants/"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, opencms

I am getting the following error message when I try to login to the member section of my OpenCMS website./

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Error reading the child resources of parent folder "/warrants/".

I am very new to java and cant understand whats the issue.. Can anyone please help..

Best Regards,
Anz

Comment: Are you using the Admin user or some user with admin rights? If not, try to use one with admin rights. If you're still getting the error, make sure your resource (/warrants folder) exists both in offline and online project, which means, it should already by published.

Comment: @Mathias.. many thanks for the reply.. yes the folder "warrants" is available in both Online and Offline version and the site was working fine till few days back. The user I tried to login has admin privileges! Is there any other reason which can throw this error? Is it possible to check the folder permissions from OpenCMS admin? Thanks again..

Comment: When you login into the OpenCms workplace, then click on the folder icon, and select the 'permissions' option, you should see the current permissions that the user (as which you are logged in as) has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to reference some source code even though you said you are new to java.

**ERR_READ_RESOURCES_1** is the error message that you are seeing. That means you don't have permission to access the folder content.

[Source code](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Content-Management-System/opencms/org/opencms/db/CmsSecurityManager.java.htm)

```
/**
         * Reads all resources below the given path matching the filter criteria,
         * including the full tree below the path only in case the <code>readTree</code> 
         * parameter is <code>true</code>.<p>
         * 
         * @param context the current request context
         * @param parent the parent path to read the resources from
         * @param filter the filter
         * @param readTree <code>true</code> to read all subresources
         * 
         * @return a list of <code>{@link CmsResource}</code> objects matching the filter criteria
         *  
         * @throws CmsSecurityException if the user has insufficient permission for the given resource (read is required)
         * @throws CmsException if something goes wrong
         * 
         */
        public List readResources(CmsRequestContext context,
                CmsResource parent, CmsResourceFilter filter,
                boolean readTree) throws CmsException, CmsSecurityException {

            List result = null;
            CmsDbContext dbc = m_dbContextFactory.getDbContext(context);
            try {
                // check the access permissions
                checkPermissions(dbc, parent, CmsPermissionSet.ACCESS_READ,
                        true, CmsResourceFilter.ALL);
                result = m_driverManager.readResources(dbc, parent, filter,
                        readTree);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dbc.report(null, Messages.get().container(
                        Messages.ERR_READ_RESOURCES_1,
                        context.removeSiteRoot(parent.getRootPath())), e);
            } finally {
                dbc.clear();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: @zawhtut.. thanks for your reply.. yes I too think its a permission issue since the folder is available.  Do you know how to check the folder permission and fix this error. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I do. You can right click on the folder and choose permission and add the group or user to apply permission to the folder. The default is "All Others" and "Admin". You can create more users in Account Management. You can assign roles to the users too. See the screenshots of account management http://www.opencms.org/en/support/features/features7/usermanagement.html